# Posso isolar com vírgulas?

Tags: ortografia, vírgula

> O filme retrata a vida de Fulano que, desempregado, sofre muitas...

O termo desempregado pode ser isolado com vírgulas?

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim, trata-se de um aposto explicativo. Os apostos geramente aparecem entre vírgulas. Podem aparecer depois de dois pontos ou travessões tb..

https://www.normaculta.com.br/aposto/

https://www.todamateria.com.br/aposto/